# Can I rollback data overwritten by SQL Server after restore?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I accidentally restored the database before checking. Can I restore my database as before the restore?

Comment: provided you have a backup before you perform the restore

Comment: If you have a back up of the database before the restore, sure.

Comment: @Squirrel I don't have a back up :')
so this is hopeless?

Comment: @Larnu I don't have a back up :') so this is hopeless?

Comment: Yep... You've completely overwritten the data. Learn from your mistake and don't accidentally `RESTORE` a database over an existing one; check the syntax you are running. (I will admit, it is pretty difficult to "accidentally" overwrite a database as you have to be very explicit to the RDBMS that that's what you want to do.)

Comment: @Larnu Oke Thank you, Noted. 
For the truth, it's not me but one of my team. I'm looking for a way to save him. 
So now I don't know what to say to my boss.

Comment: Honesty is the best policy.

Comment: A good script for operations like these, with enough safeguards, is something that can avoid situations like these. Too late for your situation now... but you will not want this to happen again. Having said that, I hope the damage is not too severe.

Comment: If a junior member of the team has managed to do a lot of damage, that's a failing in the processes, not of the junior member. It's important that the company learns from mistakes and doesn't punish people for them, otherwise when things go wrong in future (and they will, that's life) then people won't hide things which can lead to real disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to rollback data that has been overwritten in SQL Server unless it has backup data to restore. CMIIW.

Comment: There is one possible hope. Are your drives independently backed up? If so, then you can restore the files from the drive backup. This once saved a customer of ours, who had instructed us to delete a database, only to discover two weeks later, that there was some data, that he hadn't exported before the deletion.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Unfortunately drives are not independently backed up :)
but thanks for the very useful information.